# Line breaks from textarea and mysql dont appear in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea, line-breaks

How can I make text appear on diff lines in html?! They appear on diff lines in my text area when output from mysql, and also appear on diff lines inside mysql. But in the web page its all on one line. How can this be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )
```

It can handle `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n` or `\n\r` linebreaks and replaces them with a `<br />`

Example:

```
$yourText = "This is line one.\nThis is line two.";
$yourText = nl2br($yourText);
echo $yourText;
```

This will result in:

```
This is line one.<br />This is line two.
```

[Link to the manual for more information.](http://php.net/nl2br)

Comment: nl2br does the job. Thanks. I was about to write a function for this. Glad I asked.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [PHP nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br) function:

```
$string = "hello \n world";
$string = nl2br($string);
```

It's quite self-explanitory: `\n` gets replaced with `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Linebreaks` with `<br>`

```
str_replace(.N, '<br>', [element]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<pre>..Your text..</pre>` tag for that.

Comment: Didn't try this, but simply doing nl2br($string) is nicer.